# Selecting a row in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

i have a python project and a db file associated with the python file.

the db file looks like this

```
 | ID | ODP | PDP | Positive | City |
    1   120  344     3213    Jakarta
    2   131  154     1613    Bandung
```

When the user gives a input using a tkinter entry i want it so that it searches the row that has the city name

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn

def select_city(conn, input):

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE city=?", (input,))

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)

def main():
    database = db_file_path

    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:
        select_city(conn, input)
```

Change table_name in select_city with the name of your table and db_file_path in main with your database file path